# What is it called when I forget reasons something is true?

Tags: terminology

There is a phenomenon that I experience, but I do not know how it is called in respective literature, so I cannot research and read more about it.

I am an engineer, therefore it is my job to constantly learn and work with new knowledge and tools. And since I have a mind that is slightly tilted to the OCD side, I tend to care more about the most optimal solutions than my peers do. So I read and evaluate each tool from multiple perspectives, and arrive at what I believe the best choice/compromise.

However, in time, I keep using that solution. *I know it is the best solution under this and that circumstance, but I would be often long forgotten my research, as to why this particular solution is the best.* I can do a quick research and retrieve/validate the resons, but that still takes a bit of time.

I've detected this phenomenon in viturally every collague or peer that I have talked to.

**My question is:** what it is called when you know something to be true, but in order to explain why, you need to research and remember your arguments? I want to research and read more about this, but do not know how it is called in literature. Any pointers would be appreciated!

**Disambiguation from similar concepts;**

- I am **not** talking about beliefs. i.e. truths without logical reasons.
- I am **not** talking about cognitive fallacies/biases.
- It is **not** expert intuition or educated guess. Where you apply well reinforced patterns to a new input.
- It is something you *knew* to be true *according a standard you still hold.* A standard like scientific papers, research, logic, evidence etc. But you forgot the details.

**Examples;**

- I know you should water this type of plant every 3rd day. I've been watering mine that way, and it is doing great. I've read a lot about it why it should be once every 3 days, and it works just great, but I need to dig up the sources to tell the reasons why it works.
- I've researched and learned that you should salt your password hashes before storing them in a database. This is to defeat rainbow table attacks. But suppose I have forgotten why I should salt password hashes, but I still know that you should definitely salt them.
- I've read a lot about how sleep works, and I can give you practical bullet points how to improve your sleep. But suppose I've forgotten many complex biological reasons justifying this knowledge/tips.

Comment: Perhaps something like [selective retention](https://psychologydictionary.org/selective-retention/)?

Comment: Abstract knowledge, perhaps. We discover individual facts but pass them on to future generations in the form of more general or abstract structural knowledge. https://supermemo.guru/wiki/Abstract_knowledge

Comment: How is this not simply [dual process theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_process_theory), where everyday decisions and beliefs become automatic over time? Outside of perhaps certain savants, humans cannot be expected to remember the history of every past decision. In programming terms, one might say the code has already been compiled, leaving only the binary.